# RXJS - Observable with params

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have the following function that returns a http observable

```
getCountries(value) {
    return this.areasService.getCountries({key: value});
}
```

And I pass this function to a component `[search]="getCountries()"`

The problem is that I can't find a way to rerun this observable with different params

```
this.search.subscribe((data) => {
    console.log('----');
    console.log(data);
})
```

Can I send `value` to getCountries?

Comment: What about `[search]="getCountries"` and `this.search(params)` ?

Comment: It depends on how you want to rerun that Observable. Subscribe again or just reemit the same value or whatever...

Comment: Subscribe again

Comment: add `value` field to the component, and [search]="getCountries(value)|async"

Answer (score 1):

try to to use the reference to function.
in parent component (more convenient way):

```
public searchMethod = (value) => this.getCountries(value);
```

in .html use:

```
[search]="getCountries"
```

in child .ts use:

```
this.search(input).subscribe((data) => {
console.log('----');
console.log(data);
})
```

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCountries' of undefined

Comment: where is the getCountries declared?

Comment: to the parent component. `public areasService: AreasService`

Comment: I add `console.log(this)` to this componet... But when it subscribes from the child component... it console... child "this"

Comment: @Michalis please see updated version. i think its more readable and comfort way to use fat function and avoid closure.

Answer (score 0):

```
getCountries() {
    return ((value) => {
        return this.areasService.getCountries({key: value});
    });

}
```

Pass like this

```
[search]="getCountries()"
```

And subscribe like this

```
this.search('Greece').subscribe((data) => {
    console.log(data);
})
```